# Is there anyway that I can assign different name to Labels using Loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

Want to create Label with different name using loop. Because later on I want to destroy that particular Label by calling its name.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()
w.geometry('300x400')
a = 10


def remove():
    l.destroy()
                 #SUPPOSE I WANT TO DESTROY 5th LABEL.
                 #BY ASSIGNING NAME TO EACH LABEL ITS EASY TO CALL IT AND DESTROY IT


def client_info():
    pass


for i in range(15):
    l = Label(w, text=client_info)
    l.place(x=10, y=a)
    b = Button(w, text='REMOVE', command=remove)
    b.place(x=200, y=a)
    a = a + 25
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Store them in list and be like `lst[4].destroy()`.

Comment: tried.. but im getting error    -->curr_time[i - 1].config(text=string)

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Update with the new code then.